# Can't get an AlertDialog to work

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an onLongClickListener that resets some values when called.
I would like to ad an alertDialog to check if the user really does want to reset all the values. However I am having no joy making it work.

The reset section works fine on it's own but if I try to add the AlertDialog I get the following error:

**Multiple markers at this line
 - The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnLongClickListener(){}) is 
  undefined
 - Line breakpoint:SatFinder [line: 174] - onLongClick(View)**

What exactly does this mean and how can I fix it?
Many thanks.

Below is the section of code. Please note that the alert does nothing useful in this example. I will change that after I get past the error above.

```
    resetAll = new OnLongClickListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

       // set the message to display
       alertbox.setMessage("This is the alertbox!");

       // set a positive/yes button and create a listener
       alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

           // do something when the button is clicked
           public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });

       // set a negative/no button and create a listener
       alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

           // do something when the button is clicked
           public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "'No' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });

       alertbox.show();

    // Resets all values and radio buttons
    pos1_deg.setText("0.0");
    pos2_deg.setText("0.0");
    pos1_az.setText("0.0");
    pos2_az.setText("0.0");
    targetDeg.setText("0.0");
    blurg.setText("----");

    radio1.setChecked(false);
    radio2.setChecked(false);
    radio3.setChecked(false);
    radio1E.setChecked(true);
    radio2E.setChecked(true);
    radio3E.setChecked(true);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
      "Reset", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
   }

};
```

Comment: without line markers, this is a little tough; which line is 174?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that this line of code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

is actually inside of anonymous inner class which implements the interface `OnLongClickListener`.  The argument to the [AlertDialog.Builder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context%29) constructor must be a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) object.  `this` as an argument here, refers to the anonymous inner class object, which does not extend Context.  I'm guessing that your posted code fragment is inside an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) object, in which case, change the line to:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(OuterClass.this);
```

where *OuterClass* is the name of your Activity class that this method is inside.  This is the syntax used to refer to the object that an inner class is defined in.

Comment: Good explanation, I was hoping the OP would determine the difference between his code and the linked solution code, figuring out the answer himself.

Comment: I didn't bother to look at your link, but you're right, it also solves the problem.  IMO the point of a community like this is not JUST to help someone solve a problem, but also to have the solution contained in the site for future searches, not simply a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
```